# при перезагрузке остается старый контент ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть сайт на котором все страницы подгружаются ajax'ом, так вот при переходе между страницами, динамическая часть контента остается неизменной до перезагрузки страницы методом ctrl+r || f5. Привести код страницы сложно, самопис написанный индусским программистом. Понимаю что трудно что-то сказать, но хотябы догадки.

Comment: Видимо браузер кеширует ваши запросы. Настройте на сервере заголовки, чтобы страницы не кешировались.

Comment: Стоит Cache-control: no-cache

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего где то не отрабатывает запрос, либо ошибка в ответе, либо не срабатывает какое то условия для очистки контента и подгрузки нового.В девтулсе просмотрите ответы запросов, и срабатывает ли вообще запрос на новую страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, если динамическая часть контента остается не изменной до обновления, значит , что код отправки данных на сервер, стоит ниже кода вывода страниц